# Login on 12.04 LTS slow after moving /home to separate HDD

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, login, home-directory, lts

On a prior install I had moved the `/home` to a different HDD to keep the SSD for the OS only. On Saturday Ubuntu crapped out and I had to reinstall, after getting things back to the point of moving the `/home` drive again to the HDD, everything appeared fine until I logged in after editing the `fstab`.

I can log in fine, but get a black screen with the mouse pointer for about 30-50 seconds, it is pretty consistent time wise.

I figure it is something to do with some files in the new `/home/john` directories that Ubuntu is trying to locate/load at login.

I've done some cleanup in `~/.local` removing old application folders etc. But nothing seems to help.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

how about Keeping the home folder on the SSD and deleting the music,doc dwnld and all the other folders that come in the home ..create a short cut to the HHD in the Home Folder and re create those doc. music. dwnld folders in the HHD

Pros -will solve your problem

Cons -it will be an extra click

..sometimes the simplest answer is the best one